# How to convert NoneType to int in python?

Tags: python

I want to try to convert a decimal number to a binary number using stacks in Python but I got this error.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)



def divideBy2(decNumber):
    remstack = Stack()

    while decNumber > 0:
        rem = decNumber % 2
        remstack.push(rem)
        decNumber = decNumber // 2

    binString = ""
    while not remstack.is_empty():
        binString = binString + str(remstack.pop())

    return binString

print(divideBy2(42))
```

Comment: What error? And where?

Comment: A Python list is also a stack. Why a separate class?

Comment: @Daniel - Because a real programmer can write Java in any language.

Comment: @Daniel A good reason would be that a list is much more than a stack.

Answer (score 5):

Your `pop` method is missing a `return`.